# hot to create a python script in Maya that cycles thru all perspective cameras in the scene?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm trying to translate this script from MEL to Python but no luck, anyone can help?
I got to the point where I can get a list of all perspective cameras, but I can't figure out how to iterate over the current camera and look thru the next one in the list.

```
//Switch Perspective Cameras
$currentCamera = `lookThru -q`;
string $allCameras[];
//This will select perspective cameras only
$allCameras = `listCameras -p`;
int $nextCamera;
// for loop over cameras
for($pos=0;$pos<size($allCameras);$pos++)
{
if($currentCamera == $allCameras[$pos]) $nextCamera = $pos+1;
}
if($nextCamera>=size($allCameras)) $nextCamera = 0;
lookThru $allCameras[$nextCamera];
```

Comment: never mind, found the solution, had to add the word "Shape" to the current camera

Answer (score 0):

here are snippet of code :

```
cams = cmds.ls(type='camera')
for c in cams:
    cmds.lookThru(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

here the working code I came up with, this will switch to the next non perspective camera.

```
#current camera look thru
currentCamera = cmds.lookThru( q = True)
currentCamera  = (currentCamera + "Shape")
#list all cameras
cameraList = cmds.ls(type = ("camera"))
#list stratup cameras
excludeCameraList = ["frontShape","perspShape","sideShape","topShape","bottomShape","leftShape","backShape"]
#exclude startup cameras
nonStartupCameras = [x for x in cameraList if x not in excludeCameraList]
#find length
length = len(nonStartupCameras)
pos = 0
nextCamera = []
#loop thru all persp camera
for i in range(length):
    if currentCamera == nonStartupCameras[i]:
        pos = i+1
if pos >= length:
    pos = 0
#switch to next camera
nextCamera = nonStartupCameras[pos]
cmds.lookThru(nextCamera)
```